# calling recoil inside a function

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I am trying to create a **like button function** in my react app.

Main challenge is that i need to handle like function **depending on the login status** of the user.

In my component:

```js
import {LikeApi} from "../api/likeApi"

const myComponent = ({prodKey}) =>{
  const likeHandler = ()=>{
    const res = LikeApi(prodKey)
  }
  return (
  <button onClick={likeHandler} />
  )
}
```

In my Likeapi "module" (im trying to make this into a resuable module"):

```js
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { isLoggedInAtom } from "../recoil/AtomUser";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const LikeApi = (prodSeq) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const isLoggedIn = useRecoilValue(isLoggedInAtom);
  console.log(isLoggedIn);
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    navigate("/login");
  } else {
    return isLoggedIn;
  }
};
```

These are my **basic setup**.

1. when user clicks like button, likeApi module checks the login status from recoil (state management)
2. if user is not logged in, then navigate to login page.
3. eventually i will send api request to backend

**The problem is**:

- directly calling recoil in my component works

```js
  import {LikeApi} from "../api/likeApi"

const myComponent = ({prodKey}) =>{
  const res = LikeApi(fileSeq)
  return (
  <button onClick={likeHandler} />
  )
}
```

- But when i place LikeApi module (function) inside the button function, i get an error:

```js
import {LikeApi} from "../api/likeApi"

const myComponent = ({prodKey}) =>{
  const likeHandler = ()=>{
    const res = LikeApi(prodKey) 
    // throws an error
  }
  return (
  <button onClick={likeHandler} />
  )
}
```

**The error message** is:
*Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:*
*1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app*

**My question** is:
Is it not possible to get recoil value as i click a button?
Should i always first get recoil value (login status) only inside the component.

Answer (score 0):

1. 'LikeApi' module is not function component.
2. delete hook in 'LikeApi' module.
3. add to LikeApiProps and take a pure function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).